# How to use same Javascript function for different id's

Tags: javascript, html

```
function togglePlay() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  return myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
};
```

```
<audio id="myAudio1" src="https://clubajax.pythonanywhere.com/media/contact/backgroundM.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="togglePlay()" />

<audio id="myAudio" src="https://clubajax.pythonanywhere.com/media/contact/backgroundM.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="togglePlay()" />'
```

I want to use this tooglePlay() function for different ID's, so that I can pause and play the independently for each song. How can I pass the different audio id's to same function?

Comment: What are function arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function accept the id as a parameter:

```js
function togglePlay(id) {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById(id);
  return myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
};
```

Then, in your HTML, pass the id of the corresponding `audio` tag when calling `togglePlay`:

```html
<audio id="myAudio1" src="https://clubajax.pythonanywhere.com/media/contact/backgroundM.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="togglePlay('myAudio1')" />

<audio id="myAudio" src="https://clubajax.pythonanywhere.com/media/contact/backgroundM.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="togglePlay('myAudio')" />'
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but the songs play parallely when I click on both the songs. I want to stop the current playing song when I play the second song.